# comparing enum from templated class - is it safe?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

So, a simple question really, illustrated by the example below. When you compile this, the compiler appropriately(?) reports a warning (that we are comparing `barfoo<int>::bar` with `barfoo<foo>::bar`), now given `bar` is an enum - can I safely ignore this warning?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct foo
{
};

template <typename bob = int>
struct barfoo
{
  enum bar { ONE, TWO, THREE };

  bar action() const { return TWO; }
};

template <barfoo<>::bar eAction = barfoo<>::ONE>
struct IsAction
{
  template <typename bf>
  static bool check(bf const& cState)
  {
    return cState.action() == eAction;
  }  
};

int main(void)
{
  barfoo<foo> c;

  cout << IsAction<>::check(c) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Given I'm a stickler for removing warning messages, is there a way to satisfy the compiler *without moving the enum outside*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric representation of the enums will be the same, so it's safe to compare them directly (or even cast between them, although you may need to go through `int` to satisfy the compiler). If you want to silence the warning, one approach would be to cast them both to ints before doing the comparison: `(int)cState.action == (int)eAction`. You might be able to add a templated `operator==` for the enum to do this automatically - not sure on this point, though.

Alternately, depending on how you define "without moving the enum outside", you could derive from a non-templated base class that serves to hold the enum's definition, as in http://codepad.org/8bVlcas3

Comment: I think the templated `operator==` would have the same issue, the derivation I think is the cleanest answer... Thanks.

Comment: well, I meant you could do a `template<typename A, typename B> bool operator==(const barfoo<A>::bar &, const barfoo<B>::bar &)`. A bit scary, but I _think_ it would work...

Comment: Ahh, I thought you meant the `operator==` in the enum, oops... hmm.. yes, I don't think I like the above `operator==` :) I've used the derivation and it's fine - I'm waiting for the time interval before I can accept the answer... :)

Comment: @Nim, what do you mean? The only difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is that `struct` defaults to `public` visibility, while `class` defaults to `private` visibility

Comment: @bdonlan, sorry, I had not specified `public` inheritance, which is why I removed my comment.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would move it outside but to a base-class:

```
struct barenum
{ 
   enum bar { ONE, TWO, THREE };

 protected: // because we are going to derive from it without a virtual destructor
   ~barenum() {}
};

template <typename bob = int>
struct barfoo : barenum
{
  bar action() const { return TWO; }
};
```

Comment: He explicitely wrote 'is there a way to satisfy the compiler without moving the enum outside?'.

Comment: @Frerich, I think unless I cast to int, this is the best option too - this fits what I'm doing anyway, so have taken this approach. @CashCow, sorry I can't accept your answer as @bdonlan mentioned this first.

Comment: @French by "outside the class" the assumption was he meant into global or namespace scope, not into a base-class scope.

Answer (score 0):

does moving the enum into a parent of barfoo count?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct foo
{
};

struct barfoobase
{
  enum bar { ONE, TWO, THREE };
};

template <typename bob = int>
struct barfoo : public barfoobase
{
  bar action() const { return TWO; }
};

template <barfoobase::bar eAction = barfoobase::ONE>
struct IsAction
{
  template <typename bf>
  static bool check(bf const& cState)
  {
    return cState.action() == eAction;
  }  
};

int main(void)
{
  barfoo<foo> c;

  cout << IsAction<>::check(c) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

edit:
Oops, that answer has already been posted...

Comment: that 3 of us came up with the same answer may indicate what a good answer it is?